# How to install multiple In-house apps

Tags: android

I'm developing a website to deploy my android applications. Users can select multiple android applications from the android app list from the website and when they click download, all the applications have to install to the phone one by one. Check All the applications at once - Click Download - Then all the applications will be downloaded and installed automatically.
How is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a native app, there isn't a way to do this programmatically.

An example of doing it in a native app would be how Amazon does it in their appstore.  I believe they use the [Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html) to send data to the application to tell it to install an apk.  The application then downloads the apk from a server somewhere and installs it.  This will require install permissions in your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible on stock Android. You can download all of the files, it is up to the user to install them manually.